# Sticky Footer doesn't work well on Safari and Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, sticky-footer

What can be happening in this case ? It's a very nice .NET website, but when I check the website in Safari or chrome, sometimes the footer doesnt work well, and I have to scroll the page (move the scroll bar) so it fits in it's rigth place.  It's a very weird thing.

This is the sticky footer plugin I'm using , the best I've used so far, it was taken from a site http://www.drupalcoder.com/sticky-footer-plugin.html

I've already used and tried the other cssstickyfooter.com and ryanfait.com and many others, this one below has been the best I've seen so far.
But it doesn't work well on Safari and Chrome.

Check this out:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#footer").stickyFooter();
    });

    // sticky footer plugin
    (function($) {
        var footer;

        $.fn.extend({
            stickyFooter: function(options) {
                footer = this;

                positionFooter();

                $(window)
              .scroll(positionFooter)
              .resize(positionFooter);

                function positionFooter() {
                    var docHeight = $(document.body).height() - $("#sticky-footer-push").height();
                    if (docHeight < $(window).height()) {
                        var diff = $(window).height() - docHeight;
                        if (!$("#sticky-footer-push").length > 0) {
                            $(footer).before('<div id="sticky-footer-push"></div>');
                        }
                        $("#sticky-footer-push").height(diff);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

Comment: You can achieve a "sticky footer" with CSS alone and that will allow for disabled JS browsers to get the same browsing experience.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend trying a CSS only solution [link](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/). That will work on browsers with disabled javascript.

Comment: As I mentioned on my post... I tried that one, but it is not working for me. 
 I don't know if using .NET / IIS has to do with the interpretation of the codes... but I've had to design for .NET apps and it is a pain.  It's way easier when I do work for php/mysql apps, way way easier.

Comment: HTML / CSS / JavaScript is client side, the server side language makes no difference if the client side code is the same.

Comment: I too recommend using a CSS solution. Our website uses the "sticky footer" ability and it works on every browser we've tried. http://infinitas.ws - just break apart the source code to see what we did.

Comment: I don't know what's so special about this .net project that everything I know is wrong. Designing this project was painful, it works pretty well, except for thefooter in SAFARI and Chrome. Firefox and IE works wonders.  Did you see the sticky footer im using ? Is there something i could add to it to let it work well in the other browsers for some reason ?

Comment: check out my answer for a little push in the right direction.  Some minor CSS modifications and you "should" be off to the races.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how we've done [our](http://infinitas.ws) CSS ONLY solution

Markup

```
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
     <div id="header"></div>
     <div id="menu"></div>
     <div id="main"></div>
     <div id="clearfooter"></div>
 </div>
 <div id="footer">
     <div class="footer"></div>
 </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
/*General Site Design*/
body
{
    margin: 0;
}
#wrapper
{
    width: 900px; /*same width as w\idth inside "outer" element*/
}
#header
{
    height: 63px;
}
#menu
{
    width: 798px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
#main
{
    width: 780px;
    margin-left: 60px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

/*Footer Layout*/
#clearfooter
{
    height: 75px; /*same as footer height*/
}
#footer
{
    width: 900px;
    height: 75px;
    background-image: url(Images/Footer_bg.gif);
    margin: -75px auto 0; /*opposite px to height*/ 
    z-index:10;
}
.footer
{
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 800px;
}
```

Comment: notice how the "footer" is outside of the "wrapper".  Essentially it's a completely separate element outside of the rest of the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the one over at [CSS-Tricks?](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/jquery-sticky-footer/)

markup

```
<div id="footer">
    Sticky Footer
</div>
```

css

```
#footer { height: 100px; }
```

script

```
// Window load event used just in case window height is dependant upon images
$(window).bind("load", function() { 

       var footerHeight = 0,
           footerTop = 0,
           $footer = $("#footer");

       positionFooter();

       function positionFooter() {

                footerHeight = $footer.height();
                footerTop = ($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()-footerHeight)+"px";

               if ( ($(document.body).height()+footerHeight) < $(window).height()) {
                   $footer.css({
                        position: "absolute"
                   }).animate({
                        top: footerTop
                   })
               } else {
                   $footer.css({
                        position: "static"
                   })
               }

       }

       $(window)
               .scroll(positionFooter)
               .resize(positionFooter)

});
```

[DEMO LINK](http://css-tricks.com/examples/jQueryStickyFooter/)

Comment: That one is really cool, but the Footer 'moves' and I don't want it to 'move' or slide whenever I'm moving the page, that is wrong !

Comment: but that's the whole reason for using a JS style sticky footer... so that it moves as you scroll.

If you want a fixed footer, then you go purely CSS

Comment: A pure CSS solution is in my other answer.